# Radiobutton should select according to the data from service Objective-C (Re-Posted)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, radio-button

i have a issue with the selection of radio button from service. I have 1 question with 3 radiobuttons each. In question 1 i have 3 radiobuttons (John,Mike,David) and outlets are connected to groupButtons (_hasNameRadioButton). Below is the service

```
{
    "DataTable": [
                  {
                      "EmpNames": {
                          "empName": "David",
                          "empid": "243",
                          "empEdu": "B.Tech"

                      }
                  }
                  ]
}
```

How can i set the radiobutton to David.

This is what i have tried. but could not have any idea how to do

```
#pragma mark - MRConnection Delegate Methods

- (void)jsonData:(NSDictionary *)jsonDict
{
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    NSMutableArray *jsonArr;
    jsonArr=[jsonDict objectForKey:@"DataTable"];
    if (![jsonArr isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {

        if ([[jsonArr objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"EmpNames"]) {
            NSMutableDictionary *userDict=[[jsonArr objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"EmpNames"];

            _txtempId.text=[userDict objectForKey:@"empid"];
            _txtempEdu.text=[userDict objectForKey:@"empEdu"];
            groupButtons


            NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userDict objectForKey:@"empName"]];

            if ([str isEqualToString:@"John"]) {
                [_hasNameRadioButton setSelected:YES];
            }
            else if ([str isEqualToString:@"Mike"]) {
                [_hasNameRadioButton setSelected:YES];
            }
            else if ([str isEqualToString:@"David"]) {
                [_hasNameRadioButton setSelected:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this mean "In question 1 i have 3 radiobuttons (John,Mike,David) and outlets are connected to groupButtons (_hasNameRadioButton). Below is the service" ??
what is groupButtons? Add code where you connect your outlet.

Comment: what is this hasNameRadioButton?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([jsonArr isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.count; i++) {
                if ([[jsonArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"EmpNames"]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *userDict=[[jsonArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"EmpNames"];

        _txtempId.text=[userDict objectForKey:@"empid"];
        _txtempEdu.text=[userDict objectForKey:@"empEdu"];
        groupButtons


        NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userDict objectForKey:@"empName"]];

        if ([str isEqualToString:@"John"]) {
            [_hasNameRadioButton setSelected:YES];
        }
        else if ([str isEqualToString:@"Mike"]) {
            [_hasNameRadioButton setSelected:YES];
        }
        else if ([str isEqualToString:@"David"]) {
            [_hasNameRadioButton setSelected:YES];
        }
    }
            }}
```

Comment: what is the use of these three conditions `if ([str isEqualToString:@"John"]) {
            [_hasNameRadioButton setSelected:YES];
        }
        else if ([str isEqualToString:@"Mike"]) {
            [_hasNameRadioButton setSelected:YES];
        }
        else if ([str isEqualToString:@"David"]) {
            [_hasNameRadioButton setSelected:YES];
        }` whatever you set as setSelected:YES

Comment: u have problem with displaying data or displaying selected data? my this code is displaying all data